# Reshaping numpy 3D array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, 3d, reshape

I have a dataset with dimensions: (32, 32, 73257) where 32x32 are pixels of a single image.

How do I reshape it to (73257, 1024) so that every image is unrolled in a row?

So far, I did:

```
self.train_data = self.train_data.reshape(n_training_examples, number_of_pixels*number_of_pixels)
```

and it looks like I got garbage instead of normal pictures. I am assuming that reshaping was performed across wrong dimension...??

Comment: You need to swap axes, moving the 73257 dimension to the front, then reshape.

Comment: @hpaulj and how do I do that? I am not so proficient with numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, first get every image in a column, then transpose:

```
self.train_data = self.train_data.reshape(-1, n_training_examples).T
```

The memory layout of your array will not be changed by any of these operations, so two contiguous pixels of any image will lay 73257 bytes apart (assuming a `uint8` image), which may not be the best of options if you want to process your data one image at a time.  You will need to time and validate this, but creating a copy of the array may prove advantageous performance-wise:

```
self.train_data = self.train_data.reshape(-1, n_training_examples).T.copy()
```

Comment: I was thinking of something more like `data.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(N,32*32)`, but don't know if the order of the flattened 32x32 part is right or not.